# Rename title of WinForms form

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, rename

How do I rename the name of already created Windows Form? Currently, its default name is `Form1` and when the application runs its name is shown in the top-left side of window. 
*How do I rename this text to `MyForm`?*

Refactoring changes the name of the .cs files, but the text in window does not change.
Moreover, I tried to change default icon of the form by using `Project->Properties->Browse to the location of the .ico file`, but the default icon didn't change. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: The Properties -> Project Icon property is used to change the executable's icon and not the icon displayed by the Form. See the Form's Icon property to change the Form's Icon.

Comment: The default `Name` of your form is also the same to the default `Text` of your form.

Answer (score 7):

You would need to change the Form's `Text` property;

This can be done VIA the properties or within code;

[image]

Or (from the constructor)

```
this.Text = "MyForm";
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: There is no Text property in Properties of Form. Instread there are properties such as Name of file, Full Path, Action when building, etc..

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov Then I think you're looking in the wrong place, have you tried (from your Form1's constructor) to change it VIA code? (i.e. `this.Text = "MyForm";`)

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov you are mixed up with properties of `Form.cs` (File propeties).

Comment: @Hexie the OP also wants to rename his `Form`, you miss that.

Comment: No he doesn't. He wants to change the text displayed in the title bar. That's set by the `Text` property. All objects that inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` have it. This answer is correct as it stands.

Comment: @KingKing Also - the question reads:
`Refactoring changes the name of the .cs files, but the text in window does not change.` making it sound as if he has already changed the Form's name. I agree with Cody Gray unfortunately.

Comment: @Hexie this question is made italic: *`How do I rename this text to MyForm`* whereas `this text` was mentioned before in `... its default name is Form1 ...`

Comment: @Hexie OK, it looks like that the OP even doesn't differentiate the `Name` and the `Text` of the form, he possibly wants to change the `Text` of his form.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Text` property of the Form in designer mode.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Text property** of the Form in designer mode.